# Using apple textures in apps?

Tags: ios, app-store

Would apple accept apps which use textures from there existing apps, like the wood from garageband etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if they'd reject the app or not, but that's only a tangential matter to the more important issue that you'd be using someone else's content in your app.

Original content is best, content which you are licensed to use is also acceptable, but directly copying content from someone else's work to enhance your own is not acceptable.

If you're just mimicking the textures, then that's another matter.  A bit more of a grey area in terms of arguing whether it's copying or not, and they may see it either way.  (It's a lot more subjective.)  But to "use textures from their existing apps" is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the use of such textures is a kind of encouragement, or license (not in the technical sense), for developers to use the same or similar textures. For example, Apple first used the 'brushed metal' texture in iTunes. Other developers then started using the texture. Apple didn't complain about this. Eventually Apple formalised it by putting the 'brushed metal' texture in the SDK as one one the window options.

Comment: @cannyboy: If the textures are available as part of the development platform (say, as built-in style themes) then that's another story.  But if they're not explicitly available and if you're considering copying them, I imagine that would be frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

They will not reject the app but it will get flagged for copyright if you upload an app containing apple textures or sounds to another app store etc. Google Play Store.